# Git rebase favor newer changes

Tags: git, git-rebase, rebase

**I am in the process of squashing commits on a git repository.**

While doing this, I am running into some merge conflicts.  I want to always favor the newest commits (still while squashing).

For example, if my conflicting commits were something like:

```
commit abcfoobar
Author: Foo
Date:   Wed Feb 3 15:03:54 2016 -0800

    Example Name

commit bazbar
Author: Baz
Date:   Tue Feb 2 16:51:55 2016 -0800

    Commit #2
```

Then, when squashing, it would automatically favor the changes on commit `abcfoobar` over `bazbar` (because `abcfoobar` is the newest [see the date]).

**Can I do a `git` rebase (to squash) that automatically favors the changes from the newest commits?**

Comment: `>` is not a highlighter, please stop using it as such. It is for denoting **quotations**. If you feel the need to highlight the actual question inside your question, you probably need to include fewer irrelevant details.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
git rebase -X theirs <upstream>
```

**Note** From the man page:

Note that a rebase merge works by replaying each commit from the working branch on top of the `<upstream>` branch. Because of this, when a merge conflict happens, the side reported as ours is the so-far rebased series, starting with `<upstream>`, and theirs is the working branch. In other words, the sides are swapped.

Edit:
If you are trying to simply choose the most recent commit based on date/time then there probably isn't any easy way to do this and for good reason. The best thing you can do in this situation is to resolve the conflicts manually.

Comment: I don't think this is quite what he is looking for, as the commits he is rebasing are not necessarily more recent than those he is rebasing onto.

Comment: Ah I see, yes that would be different. That sounds like a really bad idea.